# Is it possible to have nested "includes" in emacs org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm writing documentation and one of my documents has started getting really bulky. I decided to break it up into sections and include them all in a main section, but I realized that it's not possible for me to correctly export an html file when I do that.

**Example:**

I have a main org file:

```
#+TITLE: SO Example
#+LaTeX_CLASS: memoir
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil LaTeX:nil TeX:nil

* 1st Level
This is the first level.
#+INCLUDE: "nested_includes.org"
```

`nested_includes.org` looks like:

```
** 2nd Level
This is the second level
#+INCLUDE: "single_include.org"
```

`single_include.org` looks like:

```
*** 3rd Level
This is the third level
```

I build my HTML file using the following command:

`C:\...\emacs\bin\emacs.exe parent.org --batch -q --no-site-file --load C:\...\site-lisp\org-html-so.el -f org-export-as-html --kill`

This is what my org-html-so.el looks like:

```
(setq org-export-author-info nil)
(setq org-export-creator-info nil)
(setq org-export-time-stamp-file nil)
(setq org-export-with-timestamps nil)
```

When I build, I end up getting something like this:

[image: result]

Meanwhile, I'm expecting something like this:

[image: expected]

Is this a known issue/limitation with emacs org mode?
Is there a way for me to increase include depth?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect from the function you are using for export that you have an older version of `org-mode`.  In version 8 of org-mode the export functionality was rewritten.  I've had a quick look at how I can get this working with the version of org I have installed with my emacs.  So for me:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-version`

gives:

> Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ c:/dev/emacs/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/org/)

Which is shipped with my version of emacs 24.5.  Given the same files you created.  I changed `org-html-so.el` to read:

```
(require 'org)
(require 'ox) 
(require 'ox-html)
(setq org-export-author-info nil)
(setq org-export-creator-info nil)
(setq org-export-time-stamp-file nil)
(setq org-export-with-timestamps nil)
```

Then the emacs invocation was:

`emacs.exe parent.org --batch -q --no-site-file --load org-html-so.el -f org-html-export-to-html --kill`

**Include Depth**

This version of include does not seem to limit depth, it does though remember files previously included regions to ensure includes are not recursive.

**Upgrading**

If you have an earlier version of emacs: you can either upgrade your version of emacs, or you can install a newer version of org, into your existing installation.

To install the newer version through the package manager or install it locally from github.  See the page in installation in the [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation).

It's worth upgrading, in the least because the later versions are more actively you can take advantage of the latest features.  For example you might like the support for html themes [org-html-themes](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm going to check if I have that export function in my version otherwise I'll upgrade and try again. I'll reward the answer when I confirm it's correct.

Comment: I think you should at least have version 8 to get the ox.el based version of the exporter.  Note there's a difference between `org-html-export-to-html` and `org-html-export-as-html`: the former exports to file as your require, the latter to a buffer that will have no associated file.